# How do I get all child text from a div and separate with a space?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have this:

```
<div id ="element">
    <span>Hey</span>
    <div>
         <span>What up?</spa>
    </div>
    Yeah more text here.
</div>
```

How can I get all of the text in the note and it's descendants in a single text line with a space between each new child? I am looking for.

```
'Hey What up? Yeah more text here.'
```

I tried:

```
var text = document.getElementById("element").textContent;
```

But that makes all the words bunched up like.

```
'HeyWhat up?Yeah more text here.'
```

Note the amount of child elements is dynamic and it might just be 5 or 100.

Comment: Using `.textContent` should be giving you all the space too. Is that the actual HTML or is it compressed for spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over all the child nodes recursively to find text nodes.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#element");
const text = [];
div.childNodes.forEach(function check(child){
  if(child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE){
    text.push(child.nodeValue.trim());
  }
  child.childNodes.forEach(check);
});
console.log(text.join(' '));
```

```html
<div id ="element">
    <span>Hey</span>
    <div>
         <span>What up?</span>
    </div>
    Yeah more text here.
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you decide to do a shallow copy using the spread operator for `[...div.childNodes]` and `[...child.childNodes]`?

Comment: @RobertCooper It is necessary to convert it to an array so `forEach` can be used.

Comment: It seems to work without a shallow copy here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-comment-on-shallow-copy-n1e4t

Comment: @RobertCooper Thanks for informing me. `NodeList.forEach` was not always supported.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#element").textContent.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <span>Hey</span>
  <div>
    <span>What up?</spa>
  </div>
  Yeah more text here.
  This is <u>Nice</u>
  
  <i>One</i>
  <div>
    <p><b>!</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```